# Boot repair on different drive

Tags: boot, grub2

In my setup I have my system boot straight in to Windows OS installed on my main drive by default.
Only if I go in to my BIOS and boot from a secondary drive it will load a GRUB bootloader where I manually select Ubuntu and boot in to this Ubuntu OS which is on that secondary drive.

This has worked like that for some time until now. Now when I boot from the secondary drive I still see my GRUB boot menu but if I select ubuntu I get an error:

> Error: File not found
>
> Error: You need to load the kernel first

It seems like I need to perform a boot repair. I have found many answers that explain how to do that but none for my specific case where I want to leave the bootloader on my main drive untouched and only fix the GRUB loader on the secondary drive.

How to I fix the boot loader on a secondary drive without affecting the main windows boot loader?

Comment: You probably need to correct errors in the Ubuntu drive. If the boot was working before there's no point in using Boot Repair, it is NOT for such cases.

Comment: I can see the drive and its ubuntu partition on my Windows OS. I am not sure how I would correct any errors.

Comment: http://ccm.net/faq/3505-repair-file-system-errors-on-ubuntu

Comment: Do not run any Boot-Repair auto fixes with two drives. In BIOS mode,  It always installs grub to all drives. But you can run the Summary Report and post link, so we can review configuration.